# Creating 2 dynamic cell prototypes in my ios swift TableView with different heights

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have to create a UIView Table in swift with 2 prototype cells, each having different heights. My first cell will only have a label and a button in same line, so its height should not be too much. Where as second cell will be having a image, 4 labels etc. so I need height for this.
Is there a way I can change the height of dynamic tableview cell in code or IB?

Thanks![image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your controller as `delegate` for your `UITableView`. Then implement the optional function

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0
      return 180
    else 
      return 40 }
```

Answer (score 1):

could you use the function:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    // return height for each cell
}
```

sorry if I've misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

this is a method you can use to set the height of all your cell according to the indexpath  that is a table view delegate method .  set the height of cell it it programatically . if you want to set the height through Ui that you can set a static height for all the cell .